# need basic rspec help for testing class behavior and command line output

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've spent 3 hrs starring at this and need some help.

I'm pretty new to RSpec and I'm trying to write test for my behavior of a class called "game"

I want to test that when called game.play sends a 3x3 grid to the output....that's all I want to do. I have the RSpec book and I'm trying real hard to figure this out but I'm stumped.
I've marked the places I think are key as "FIXME"

here are my test so far...

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

# the universe is vast and infinite....and...it is empty

describe "the game class" do
  it "must output a 3x3 game grid on the CLI" do
    player_h = double('human', :player_h => "X") # FIXME - do I stub or mock this?
    player_c = double('computer', :player_c => "O")# FIXME - do I stub or mock this?
    game = Game.new(player_h, player_c)

    #FIXME - how do I get the line below to read this as if it where coming from SDOUT on the cli?
    should_receive(:puts).with("a #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n")
    game.play
  end
  it "must have a human player" do
    pending "human is X"
  end
  it "must have a computer player" do
    pending "ai is O"
  end
end
```

and here is the class I'm building this test for (yes I know that's backwards...I should be writing the test and THEN the code...but like I said, I'm a noob at this...the entire game code is already written...I'm really just tying to understand RSpec now.)...

```
require_relative "player"
#
#Just a Tic Tac Toe game class
class Game
  #create players
  def initialize(player_h, player_c)
    #bring into existence the board and the players
    @player_h = player_h
    @player_c = player_c
    #value hash for the grid lives here
    $thegrid = {
        :a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ",
        :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ",
        :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "
    }
    #make a global var for drawgrid used by player
    $gamegrid = drawgrid

  end
  #display grid on console
  def drawgrid

    board = "\n"
    board << "a #{$thegrid[:a1]}|#{$thegrid[:a2]}|#{$thegrid[:a3]} \n"
    board << "----------\n"
    board << "b #{$thegrid[:b1]}|#{$thegrid[:b2]}|#{$thegrid[:b3]} \n"
    board << "----------\n"
    board << "c #{$thegrid[:c1]}|#{$thegrid[:c2]}|#{$thegrid[:c3]} \n"
    board << "----------\n"
    board << "  1 2 3 \n"
    return board

  end
  #start the game
  def play
    #draw the board
    puts drawgrid
    #make a move
    #alternate player turns
  end

end
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC in the RSpec book they pass in an IO object, which is mocked in the tests, but it should also work if you expect `STDOUT` to receive the puts:

```
STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("foo")
```